# java native loadlibrary cannot load the library - Linux fedora25 java8

Tags: java, c++, linux, jna, fedora-25

I am trying to load a dynamic c++ library I compiled on my system in order to do a wrapper in java. I have been able to do this in the past on windows, but here I struggle to have the library loaded. Here is the code:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

import java.io.File;

public interface libWrapper extends Library {

//  String path = "." + File.pathSeparator + "hiddenPath/lib/Dynamic";
//  System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("java.library.path") + File.pathSeparator + path);
//      System.setProperty("java.library.path", path + File.pathSeparator
//          + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));

libWrapper INSTANCE = (libWrapper)
        Native.loadLibrary(
                "libgtengine.so",
                libWrapper.class );

Pointer FrameCstructor(String name, long parent,
        double x, double y, double z,
        double rotX, double rotY, double rotZ,
        double vX, double vY, double vZ,
        double angVx, double angVy, double angVz,
        double accX, double accY, double accZ,
        double angAccX, double angAccY, double angAccZ,
        boolean addToFramelist);
}
```

I have tried to specify the location of the library with different methods with no success:

1) specify the -Djava.library.path=PATHTOLIBRARY

2) use System.setProperty, but this was of no success since I was not able to run the code. I receive a compilation error that says it could not find the function setProperty (as well as getProperty): Error:(16, 35) java:  expected

3) copy the libgteengine.so in the same folder than the libWrapper class.

I suspect that my library has the wrong architecture build?

here is the error message i get when trying to load it with method 1) and 3)

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gtengine': Native library (linux-x86-64/libgtengine.so) not found in resource path ([file:/home/ycourvoisier/Documents/Softwares/ideaIU-2017.1/idea-IU-171.3780.107/lib/idea_rt.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/Documents/Softwares/ideaIU-2017.1/idea-IU-171.3780.107/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/Documents/Development/GitLocalRepo/com-enata-java-math/target/test-classes/, file:/home/ycourvoisier/Documents/Development/GitLocalRepo/com-enata-java-math/target/classes/, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/ejml/all/0.30/all-0.30.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/ejml/core/0.30/core-0.30.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/ejml/dense64/0.30/dense64-0.30.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/ejml/denseC64/0.30/denseC64-0.30.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/ejml/equation/0.30/equation-0.30.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/ejml/simple/0.30/simple-0.30.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-csv/1.4/commons-csv-1.4.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4/javax.json-1.0.4.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.4.0/jna-4.4.0.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-jpamodelgen/5.1.4.Final/hibernate-jpamodelgen-5.1.4.Final.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api/2.2.1/javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.2.1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/javax/el/el-api/2.2.1-b04/el-api-2.2.1-b04.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-dbcp2/2.1.1/commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-pool2/2.4.2/commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.4.1212/postgresql-9.4.1212.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/easymock/easymock/3.4/easymock-3.4.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/2.2/objenesis-2.2.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.22/slf4j-simple-1.7.22.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.22/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/openjdk/jmh/jmh-core/1.17.4/jmh-core-1.17.4.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.6/jopt-simple-4.6.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-server-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-http-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-io-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jndi/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-jndi-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-util-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-maven-plugin-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/3.0.3/maven-plugin-api-3.0.3.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-model/3.0.3/maven-model-3.0.3.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-plexus/2.1.1/sisu-inject-plexus-2.1.1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.1.1/sisu-inject-bean-2.1.1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.9.4/sisu-guice-2.9.4-no_aop.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/3.0.3/maven-artifact-3.0.3.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.6/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-core/3.0.3/maven-core-3.0.3.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/3.0.3/maven-settings-3.0.3.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-settings-builder/3.0.3/maven-settings-builder-3.0.3.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/3.0.3/maven-repository-metadata-3.0.3.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-model-builder/3.0.3/maven-model-builder-3.0.3.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-aether-provider/3.0.3/maven-aether-provider-3.0.3.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-spi/1.11/aether-spi-1.11.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-impl/1.11/aether-impl-1.11.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-api/1.11/aether-api-1.11.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.11/aether-util-1.11.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/2.4/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-api/3.4/maven-plugin-tools-api-3.4.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.2.1/maven-project-2.2.1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.2.1/maven-profile-2.2.1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.2.1/maven-artifact-manager-2.2.1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/1.0-beta-6/wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-6.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-registry/2.2.1/maven-plugin-registry-2.2.1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-9-stable-1/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/classworlds/classworlds/1.1-alpha-2/classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-descriptor/2.2.1/maven-plugin-descriptor-2.2.1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-webapp-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-xml-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-servlet-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-quickstart/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-quickstart-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jaas/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-jaas-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-security-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-plus/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-plus-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jmx/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-jmx-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-annotations/9.4.0.RC1/jetty-annotations-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.1/asm-5.1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.1/asm-commons-5.1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.1/asm-tree-5.1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/javax-websocket-server-impl/9.4.0.RC1/javax-websocket-server-impl-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/javax-websocket-client-impl/9.4.0.RC1/javax-websocket-client-impl-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/javax/websocket/javax.websocket-api/1.0/javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-server/9.4.0.RC1/websocket-server-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-common/9.4.0.RC1/websocket-common-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-api/9.4.0.RC1/websocket-api-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-client/9.4.0.RC1/websocket-client-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-servlet/9.4.0.RC1/websocket-servlet-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/apache-jsp/9.4.0.RC1/apache-jsp-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/toolchain/jetty-schemas/3.1/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jasper/apache-jsp/8.5.4/apache-jsp-8.5.4.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jasper/apache-el/8.5.4/apache-el-8.5.4.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.4.2/ecj-4.4.2.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/apache-jstl/9.4.0.RC1/apache-jstl-9.4.0.RC1.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-spec/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/home/ycourvoisier/Documents/Softwares/ideaIU-2017.1/idea-IU-171.3780.107/lib/idea_rt.jar])
```

Thanks for your time and help

**EDIT**

```
public interface libWrapper extends Library {

static String path = "." + File.pathSeparator + "/home/ycourvoisier/Documents/Development/GitLocalRepo/hydros-mathLibrary/HydrosMathLibraryCode/lib/Dynamic";
static {
    System.setProperty( "jna.library.path", path + File.pathSeparator
            + System.getProperty( "java.library.path" ) );
}


libWrapper INSTANCE = (libWrapper)
        Native.loadLibrary(
                "libgtengine.so",
                libWrapper.class );
}
```

this was suggested in order to use the setProperty of System. But java returns a *illegal start of character*

**EDIT2**
here is a condensed version that should do the same, but that doesn't work either. The path is directly specified in the code, so there is no confusion about whether it is provided:

```
public class Frame {

static {
    System.setProperty( "jna.library.path", "/home/NAME/Documents/Development/GitLocalRepo/com-hidden-java-math/src" + File.pathSeparator + System.getProperty( "jna.library.path" ) );
}

public interface libWrapper extends Library {

    libWrapper INSTANCE = (libWrapper)
            Native.loadLibrary(
                    "gtengine",
                    libWrapper.class );

    Pointer FrameCstructor(String name, long parent,
            double x, double y, double z,
            double rotX, double rotY, double rotZ,
            double vX, double vY, double vZ,
            double angVx, double angVy, double angVz,
            double accX, double accY, double accZ,
            double angAccX, double angAccY, double angAccZ,
            boolean addToFramelist);
}

private Pointer ptrToCFrame;

public Frame(String name, int parent,
        double x, double y, double z,
        double rotX, double rotY, double rotZ,
        double vX, double vY, double vZ,
        double angVx, double angVy, double angVz,
        double accX, double accY, double accZ,
        double angAccX, double angAccY, double angAccZ,
        boolean addToFramelist) {

    ptrToCFrame = libWrapper.INSTANCE.FrameCstructor( name, parent,
            x, y, z, rotX, rotY, rotZ,
            vX, vY, vZ, angVx, angVy, angVz,
            accX, accY, accZ, angAccX, angAccY, angAccZ,
            addToFramelist );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try specifying `-Djna.library.path`.

Comment: @cubrr. I just tried it and does no difference. thanks

Comment: Afaik JNA (or JNI in general) only works with the C ABI. You could also try to use the undecorated library name (which would be according to specification) in this case `"gtengine"`.

Comment: In case you want to try `setProperty`, code has to be put inside a block. You could put that code inside a `static {...}` block.

Comment: @johnVernee, it doesn't accept the static block with the compilation error:illegal start of character. thanks

Comment: @johnVernee, I also tried to shorten the name of the library, but no success

Comment: Looks like interfaces can not define initializers, you'll have to do it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the loading issue of the library was to have the code changed (here I still doubt on the right way to do this)

```
public class Frame {

static {
    System.loadLibrary( "gtengine" );
}

public static native Pointer FrameCstructor(String name, long parent,
        double x, double y, double z,
        double rotX, double rotY, double rotZ,
        double vX, double vY, double vZ,
        double angVx, double angVy, double angVz,
        double accX, double accY, double accZ,
        double angAccX, double angAccY, double angAccZ,
        boolean addToFramelist);

private Pointer ptrToCFrame;

public Frame(String name, int parent,
        double x, double y, double z,
        double rotX, double rotY, double rotZ,
        double vX, double vY, double vZ,
        double angVx, double angVy, double angVz,
        double accX, double accY, double accZ,
        double angAccX, double angAccY, double angAccZ,
        boolean addToFramelist) {

    System.out.println("library: " + System.getProperty( "java.library.path" ));

    ptrToCFrame = FrameCstructor( name, parent,
            x, y, z, rotX, rotY, rotZ,
            vX, vY, vZ, angVx, angVy, angVz,
            accX, accY, accZ, angAccX, angAccY, angAccZ,
            addToFramelist );
    }
}
```

And I had to specify the path of the library *libgtengine.so.3.7* (not the shorter version *libgtengine.so*) in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. This was discovered after reading carefully the [link](http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-D002/) (in the video) provided by @mko member.

This now created other difficulties (*UnsatisfiedLinkError undefined symbol: XOpenDisplay*) that I keep for an other moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put file on LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Take a look here for a sample code:

https://github.com/mkopsnc/keplerhacks/tree/master/jnijna

If you decide to switch to JNI, take a look here:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did try from scratch your sample and it worked, but when I try it in my program it doesn't! I have set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the right value and checked it with the echo command. I have a intellij project that encloses my program. I am out of inspiration to find any solution... Could a dash (-) in the file path be a problem? why does the LD_LIBRARY_PATH not appear in the error description `not found in resource path`?

Comment: For IntelliJ, take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-D002/ This sample contains example related to configuration of JNI within IntelliJ. You need to make sure that Run/Debug configuration points to proper location.